# Hiding div based on user role

Tags: php, user-roles

I am running the following snippet on my wordpress site to display an image.  I would like to hide this div if the user role is "wholesale" (a custom role I created).  Is this possible?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'content_below_checkout_button' );
 
function content_below_checkout_button() {
   echo '<div style="text-align: center"><img style="margin-top:20px; display:inline-block;" src="/uploads/2020/07/image.png'.$photo->name.'"/></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just check inside the action if an array of the current user's roles contains the `wholesale` role.

```php
function content_below_checkout_button() {
    if ( in_array( 'wholesale', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
        echo '<div style="text-align: center"><img style="margin-top:20px; display:inline-block;" src="/uploads/2020/07/image.png'.$photo->name.'"/></div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'content_below_checkout_button' );
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the rest of your code, but I assume it was working.